# Bixby - Pass user input from once action to other

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to implement to read user input from one action and to read in other screen, like:

```
    user: xx
    Bixby: who's there?
    user: yyy
    Bixby: yyy who?

I am able to read user input yyy but unable to pass in different actions to display yyy who.
```

can you please help or guide what I am doing wrong or what will be best approach to do this kind of capsules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to cater to the specific use case for telling Bixby a knock knock joke or are you just using the format to demonstrate a general flow? The correct approach is different depending on which use case you would like to address.

Comment: Yes I am trying to implement a knock knock joke and many different capsule same like a knock knock. Is there any specific way to implement?

Comment: This might be useful as well https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-quiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would model the behavior of what you are probably trying to achieve.

```
Concepts 
 - Joke 
    - JokeQuestion (posed by 'Bixby')
    - JokeAnswer (answered by User)
Views
 - JokeResultView
 - JokeAnswerInputView
Layouts
 - JokeLayout
 - JokeQuestionLayout
 - JokeAnswerLayout
Action (all of these Actions take Joke as input AND output the Joke back)
 - GetJokeAnswerFromUser (get an Answer concept from the user and update the Interaction concept)
 - ShowJokeQuestionToUser (show the next JokeQuestion to the user)
Other Actions as needed?
```

With this arrangement, you always have access to both the JokeQuestion(s) and JokeAnswer(s) through the Joke Concept. The JokeResultView will drive what the user sees on the screen and you can build some sort of logic in your implementation to signal the beginning and the end of the Joke etc.

Try this out and see if it helps.

Comment: Are JokeQuestion and JokeAnswer just properties of the Joke concept, and not concepts in their own right?