# Bixby - Render output in input-view

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to display the input variable in other input-view screen but I am unable to do so:

```
input-view{
  match: JokeAnswer(this)

  message("#{value(this)} Who?") //need to display earlier filled input

  render{
    form{
      on-submit{
        goal: JokeAnswer
        value: viv.core.FormElement(answer)
      }
      submit-button{
        template ("Submit")
      }
      elements{
        text-input{
          id (answer)
          type (JokeAnswer)
          value("#{raw(this)}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Bixby: who's this?
User: XXX
Bixby : XXX who?
```

Is this correct way to do or any other method to resolve?

Comment: What is currently displayed when your capsule hits the `input-view` you've defined?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the answer I provided to the other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55697258/10409637